# Is Cloudflare unzipping gzipped dynamic content?

Tags: cdn, gzip, cloud

I'm using Cloudflare for a small website that is frequently accessed from mobile phones where bandwidth usage is crucial. I used to gzip every php response and this reduced my bandwidth usage, however, since I'm using Cloudflare, dynamic content going trough Cloudflare isn't gzipped anymore. Is this a feature or bug?

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation, Cloudflare GZIPs resources:

https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22064616-does-cloudflare-gzip-resources

> "we will honor your GZIP settings as long as you're passing the
>   details in a header from your web server for the files."